# Animations showing (flickering) white lines

Tags: swift, animation, transition, lines

Simple view transitions like `navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)` are showing a thin white line when transitioning. This happens at about 60% of the times, with or without shadows turned on with `shadowOpacity`.

Setting `clipsToBound = true` solves this problem but removes the shadows of my views so I can't use it. I've also tried `shouldRasterize` but doesn't help for the animation of `pushViewController`.

`shouldRasterize` does however solve the white lines for my other animation:

```
func animate(#position: CGFloat, duration: Double = 0.3, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.activeViewController.view.frame.origin.x = position }, completion: completion)
}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix those flickering white lines?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?